# AC to DC conversion speed

Tags: power-supply, relay, ac-dc

I am using a relay and an arduino to quickly turn on and off lights for a Christmas light show.  So far all of the lights have been AC power.  However I just got a snowman that runs on 12v DC power using an ac dc converter. The problem is when I send power to the lights, the converter takes too long to convert power from ac to dc and deliver power to the light strand in the snowman.  So my questions:

1. Are there faster ac to dc transformers I could use instead of the one the lights came with?
2. Is there a better way I can do this rather than use a converter?

Things I have thought about:
I was thinking since the arduino controls the relay with 5v so I could just use that to power the lights but there are multiple issues with that because of the distance the lights are located from the arduino.

Comment: You shouldn't quickly switch the AC with relays, they will wear out soon. It is  better to switch the DC with a MOSFET for example

Comment: Even a simple relay on the 12v side would work. Cars have lots of them.

Comment: Please provide a schematic of the AC-to-DC converter.

Comment: For future reference, a transformer is a device that "converts" AC to _AC_. Your device that converts AC to DC is an AC to DC _converter_.

Answer (score 1):

Mechanical relays are good for about a million operations if you buy quality, and you're not stressing the contacts at all. If you're switching once per second they might last until Christmas.  consider using solid-state relays instead. they last much longer.

> Are there faster ac to dc transformers I could use instead of the one the lights came with?

Switch the DC side instead, you can do it using a MOSFET or a bipolar transistor.